# window.onfocus() doesn't work on remote server

Tags: javascript, jquery, onfocus

I want to execute some code when user activate the browser's tab.

```
window.onfocus = function() {
  console.log('323');
};
```

On localhost this works, but doesn't work on remote server. Console is empty.

I also tried without success:

```
$(window).bind('focus', function() {
      console.log('323');
});​
```

My browser is Chrome, last version.

Comment: Have you double checked the code exists on the remote server? What browser are you using?

Comment: Your first method should be fine, and it shouldn't matter where you're running it from as it's all running locally (in your browser).

Comment: Might seem dumb, but is JavaScript enabled on your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome you need to use the jQuery `focus` function:

```
$(window).focus(function () {
    console.log('ative');
});
```

```js
$(window).focus(function () {
    console.log('ative');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```